# AsQueryable() does not return needed type in custom LINQ query using Lightswitch

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio-lightswitch

I am using Lightswitch to build my application and I have the following problem.

In my database, I have three tables:

- Article
- Provider
- ArticleProvider

Article and Provider have a many-to-many relation, therefore junction table ArticleProvider is needed.

Now, I want a screen in my application where the user can choose a provider and sees all articles which have a relation to this provider.

Using SQL, I would to it like this (123 is the Provider_Id I want to select).

```
SELECT * 
FROM Article a 
WHERE a.Id IN 
    (SELECT ap.Article_Id FROM ArticleProvider ap WHERE ap.Provider_Id=123)
```

In my Lightswitch application, I created a Query by clicking on the "Articles" Table in my Datasource and choosed "Add Query". I added a parameter `ProviderId` and switched to the source code editor to create my custom query:

```
partial void ArticleByProvider_PreprocessQuery(int? ProviderId, 
                                               ref IQueryable<Article> query)
{ 
    ...
}
```

Next I started to create my Linq Query. I think I need an `IQueryable<ArticleProvider>` Query to filter by them, so I tried:

```
(from art in query select art.ProviderQuery).AsQueryable<ArticleProvider>()
```

But, when trying this, I get a compile time error saying that this type can not be converted. So I tried this and it compiles fine:

```
(from art in query select art.ProviderQuery)
    .AsQueryable<IDataServiceQueryable<ArticleProvider>>()
```

However, when using the returned `IQueryable apList` in my next query:

```
from ap in apList where ap.Provider.Id == 123 select ap.Article.Id
```

It seems that the fields `Provider` and `Article` can not be found. Also Visual Studio's code completion does not suggest these fields, only lots of methods and fields which are not in my database.

How can I solve this problem?

I played around with casts and other method calls like `ToList()`, but I get always stuck at this point. I am new to Linq and C#. Thank you in advance for any help.

---

**EDIT:**
I checked the return type of the first query by using:
`var temp = (from art in query select art.ProviderQuery).AsQueryable()`

The returned type is `System.Linq.IQueryable<Microsoft.LightSwitch.IDataServiceQueryable<LightSwitchApplication.ArticleProvider>>`

Comment: "Also Visual Basic's code completion" ? Then why you use `c#` tag?

Comment: Sorry, meant Visual Studio. I'll correct this.

Comment: can you just remove the generic parameters from your code and assign them using var keyword and determine the return parameters, like the following; var temp = (from art in query select art.ProviderQuery).AsQueryable()

Comment: @daryal did this, see my edit in the post.

Comment: @w4rumy can you try converting all the code and post the results?

Comment: @daryval The result when using to generic parameters is the same as when I am using them. I get compile time errors saying that the fields `Provider` and `Article` can not be found (the same as described above).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are in the PreprocessQuery
This is for filtering data further, not adding extra.

If you look around a little this is mentioned a lot.

Comment: So, where do I need to place the query in order to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0):

Give this query a try and see if this works:

```
partial void ArticleByProvider_PreprocessQuery(int? ProviderId, 
                                               ref IQueryable<Article> query)
{
     query.Where(art => art.ArticleProviders
                              .Any(artProv => artProv.Provider.Id == ProviderId));
}
```

The idea is to get all Articles that at least matches the Provider Id.

Note: Haven't tested this code myself. But the idea should be there.

Comment: What is x and y? Where do I get them from?

Comment: This just lambda syntax, they "represent" an entity. "x" represents an Article, & "y" represents an ArticleProvider. It's not so obvious for the "x", but you'll see that "y" can access all of the properties of an ArticleProvider.